# Generalized Lagrange Multiplier Theorem.

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Let $f,g\in C^1(U,\mathbb{R})$, such that $U$ is open and non-empty, and let $a\in U$ be a value such that $f$ attains a local extreum under the constraint $g(x)=0$ and $\nabla g(a)\neq 0$. Then there is $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, s.t. 
$$\nabla f(a)=\lambda \nabla g(a)$$

I know how to prove the above Lagrange multiplier theorem, but was wondering how to generalize it to $n$ constraints. That is:
$$\nabla f(a)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i (\nabla g_i)(a)$$

I know the proof is similar, but I am not sure how to formalize it (using the implicit function theorem and not manifolds). Also, are there any good links for a proof to the above generalization. I could only find one, and couldn't understand it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\textbf {g}(\textbf {x})=\textbf{0}$ as a manifold (Namely, $\textbf{G}$) (this can be done under regularity conditions, such as $\textbf{g}\in C^{\infty}$)

From this point of view, the question of looking for the necessary condition for a point to minimize $f_{|\textbf{g}=\textbf{0}}$ can be restated as follows: "given $\varphi(t): I\rightarrow\textbf{G},\ \varphi(0)=\textbf{x*}$, which are the necessary condition for $\textbf{x*}$ to be a minimum point?"

From a straight application of Fermat's theorem, we get that, $\forall \varphi: \varphi(0)=\textbf{x*}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(\varphi(t))|_{t=0}=0$.

Thus, using the chain rule: $\nabla f(\textbf{x*})\cdot \varphi'(0)=0$

This means that $\nabla f(\textbf{x*})\in T_{\textbf{x*}}\textbf{G}^{\perp}$, and so it can be expressed as a linear combination of $\nabla g_m(\textbf{x*})$

$\begin{equation}
\nabla f(\textbf{x*})=\sum_m\lambda_m\cdot\nabla g_m(\textbf{x*})
\end{equation}$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't learnt about manifolds yet. Is there anyway to prove it using the implicit function theorem. Ill add this to my question. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: every manifold can locally be expressed as the graph of a smooth function.